# How to map array in JSON to array/List in Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring-mvc

I 've been searching for many posts but I can't find a simple solution.

I need to post a JSON object, with a property of array to the controller and map each property correctly.

For many attempts , I use below work around to achieve :

The to exitsingUsers is somehow like:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

and the param I post is:

```
$.ajax({
     url: XXXXX.do",
     type:'POST',
     data:{
        disableUserIdsJSON: JSON.stringify(exitsingUsers),//I stringify the array here
        //may have somethingelse: 'else',....
    },
```

In the controller , I write this to parse the param:

```
public List<User> getUserList(@RequestParam String disableUserIdsJSON,HttpSession session) throws IOException, SQLException {//here i accept the param as String
    List<Integer> exceptUserIds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(disableUserIdsJSON,new TypeReference<List<Integer>>(){});//parse the string back to list
```

I do hope to not transform the JSON to string and then parse the string in java code,which is not intuitive.

Is there a way to **directly** map the param from to a java List/array in Spring MVC?

Comment: Please don't post JSON as a form parameter.

Comment: I am not using a form. Just a simple ajax. Why no JSON?

Comment: You're sending JSON within form data. Don't do that. Send it directly in the body as `application/json` content.

Comment: So I add  `contentType:"application/json`  when sending ajax, then how to map in Java side directly ?

Comment: Look into `@RequestBody`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I search for some posts and it seems that `@RequestBody` maps the JSON object to a java pojo object.So if My data is :[1,2,3], I use `@RequestBody` Integer[] arrays, which works.   But what if my JSON object does have multiple properties:{array:[1,2,3],name:'myName'}, what kind of Java object should I use if I do not have a pojo class to one-one mapping this?

Comment: That what you want is not possible, without an own pojo. Wherefrom should jackson know what kind of data-type is the next?

Comment: If the JSON keys names are known, use a POJO where the field names match the JSON keys. If they aren't known, use a `Map`.